# Rails :before_save upcase private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-save

I have two methods in my model which makes changes to the registration field before inserting it in to the DB. The `strip_whitespace` method works. However, the `make_uppercase` does not.

I have also tried passing *just* the `make_uppercase` method to the `before_save` callback. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle_class
  belongs_to :vehicle_make

  before_save :strip_whitespace, :make_uppercase

  # Strip whitespace from registration field before inserting it in to the DB
  def strip_whitespace
    self.registration.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
  end

  # Make all characters uppercase before inserting it in to the DB
  def make_uppercase
    self.registration.upcase
  end

  private :strip_whitespace, :make_uppercase

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
def make_uppercase
  self.registration.upcase!
end
```

The bang method (upcase!) modifies the receiver - in this case self.registration.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `upcase!` and not just `upcase`

or redefine the method like that:

```
def make_uppercase
  self.registration = self.registration.upcase
end
```

Comment: Thanks Zozo, @AndreOgle just beat you to it. I appreciate you taking the time, all the same.